# I want when I make double click the element drop

Tags: javascript, html

I need help because I can't make double clicking
drop the element.

```js
var lista = document.getElementById("uno");

lista.onclick = function(event) {
  lista.style.position = 'absolute';
  lista.style.zIndex = 1000;

  document.body.append(lista);

  function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
    lista.style.left = pageX - lista.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
    lista.style.top = pageY - lista.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
  }

  moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

  function onMouseMove(event) {
    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
  }

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

  lista.ondblclick = function() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  }
};
```

```css
.row1 {
  position: relative;
}

#uno {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 6vw;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row1">
    <div id="uno"></div>
  </div>


  <script src="scriptV\ejercicio3.js"></script>
</body>
```

What is my mistake?

If I put

```
lista.onclick = function () {
document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
```

It works but I want double click and I don't know how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below works for me.
I moved the functions `moveAt` and `onMouseMove` and `lista.ondblclick` outside the scope of of the `lista.onclick` method, and also added a boolean, `locked` so that the event listener is only added and removed when it is not locked / locked respectively:

```
var lista = document.getElementById("uno");
let locked = false;

function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
    lista.style.left = pageX - lista.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
    lista.style.top = pageY - lista.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
}
    
function onMouseMove(event) {
    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
}


lista.onclick = function (event) {
    console.log("sng");
    if(!locked){
        console.log("not locked");
        locked = true;
    
    lista.style.position = 'absolute';
    lista.style.zIndex = 1000;

    document.body.append(lista);
    }
    

    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

    

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

    
};  

lista.ondblclick = function () {
    console.log("dbl")
    if(locked){
        console.log("locked")
        locked = false;
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    }      
}
```

Comment: But he problem lista.ondblclick = . . . doesn´t work

Comment: Apologies - misunderstood the question - have updated the answer now.

Comment: Thank you!! It works perfectly, I am very grateful to you, the truth is that since I am a novice I did not think about the Boolean. I thank you very much.

Comment: I have tried but says me this: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputations to cast a vote, but your comments have been recorded.